# IBM Mobile First Server OAuth with JWT Authentication - Incorrect JWT Format error

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing a performance test script for hybrid mobile application using Rational Performance Tester V9.0 & V8.7.

The mobile application sends the request to IBM Mobile First Server v8.0 which authenticates its user using OAuth with JWT (JSON Web Token).

I tried enhancing the script and replayed but it fails at login step in an API which requests for token **/mfp/api/az/v1/token**

Below mentioned is the request & response for the API call,

**URI: POST /mfp/api/az/v1/token**

**Request:**

client_assertion=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%3D%3D.eyJpc3MiOiJlQmFua2luZyR3ZWIiLCJzdWIiOiI2MWVjZDI2Ni0zY2EyLTQ4ZWMtODNjNi02NzE5OTBlYzc3ZTgiLCJleHAiOjE1Mzk3Nzc3NjMxNzQsImlhdCI6MTUzOTc3NzcwMzE3NCwianRpIjoiLTQ0NjkwNTY3Njc4NzAzMTYyNzEiLCJhdWQiOiJhei92MS90b2tlbiJ9.nMcfmOPDcLjONOXhF%2B3mArM87AiPfqEPp5Bk815f9Dg7VaaIgY41jeSmlWASCdmjf9Cno3%2BwHGom%2BzAEGQDdFkmBjLpCY7TnCAv9j8HzIPDubYdSQW2pq7WKVz%2FvEQ8Z5Pa8jh8aAMTlrsBnjlPoiVfcqHBh%2F2vpHZnKvkSoCOcA2TAeJnioSlp4vpWOc26IsMwKYMqZlVs9K2Z8JwHQvESKlzDu9etxYnnQfxyqunwhG%2B5T9GKgMmCAo1%2BBGqqsEtTwOG5UmhoyYIYbMnNHzHFdl8fWwMMOtpf%2F3RqjBYNeAsZ%2BTuGkskLlA5hrLiHmfOhzPYstr8tCO2IMLbTpjQ%3D%3D&code=5059335353176972418&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fuatirmob.qcdib.com%2Fmfp%2Fapi%2Faz%2Fv1%2Fauthorization%2Fredirect%2F17553a31-f583-44f9-9b7a-d8fab31b3bff&client_assertion_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Aclient-assertion-type%3Ajwt-bearer

**Response:
{"errorCode":"invalid_client","errorMsg":"Incorrect JWT format"}**

I noticed that the client_assertion value carries dynamic data in JSON form when I decrypted with https://jwt.io/#debugger

Also, developed encryption logic mentioned in IBM mobile first site to generate the **client_assertion** value referring this link: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/08/09/performance-testing-for-mobilefirst-foundation-8-0/

It was not successful after following the above steps.

Please provide solution to handle the **/mfp/api/az/v1/token** request and generate access token which will passed in the subsequent requests.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have documented performance testing instruction for JMeter.

Please refer to link here for more details - https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/08/09/performance-testing-for-mobilefirst-foundation-8-0/

Please refer to section "Sign grant code" and ensure you are following steps properly [ https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/08/09/performance-testing-for-mobilefirst-foundation-8-0/#sign-grant-code ]

Comment: Thanks @Kavitha Varadarajan. We referred the same link and did some modifications according to the mobile application and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try the latest Mobilefirst v8 build (late Oct 2018) which will fix this.

Comment: I am using the latest Mobilefirst v8 build with the fixes. Still facing the same error.